# spawn babel-node ENOENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-node

I am building a **react** app from scratch with `yarn` and not `npm` as yarn is fast than npm. I am not using `create-react-app` command to create my react app just to make sure I do everything from scratch.

I have a webpack file with basic configuration snippet copied from [webpack site](https://webpack.js.org/).

Please see I am using `babel-node` to run my project, as I have ES6 `import` in my node `server.js` file.

In below file, to tell `pm2` to use `babel-node` instead of regular `node`, *interpreter* is used

#### package.json

```
 {
  "name": "advanced-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/server.js",
  "author": "GopiGorantala",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pm2 start lib/server.js --watch --interpreter babel-node"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "pm2": "^3.2.9"
  }
}
```

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import config from './config';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {answer: 42});
});

app.listen(config.port, function listenHandler() {
  console.info(`running on ${config.port}`);
});
```

when i run my application with `yarn dev`, I don't get the server as online but instead I get as `errored`

[image]

I tried to check the logs with `yarn pm2 logs` to check on the error but I don't get much information.. Please see screenshot below

[image]

Note: please see, I am adding my packages using `yarn add --dev` command

Question: I am receiving `spawn babel-node ENOENT` error. How can I make sure I don't run into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this finally with the help of [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9835)

I have to install `babel-cli` globally to make [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) run the babel-node properly..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all webpack configs work with jsx.  WP should look something like this.

```
module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',
module: {
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader']
  }
 ]
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
},
output: {
path: __dirname + '/dist',
publicPath: '/',
filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
contentBase: './dist'
}
};
```

Comment: tried this, but didn't work, maybe it has something to do with babel settings.. `pm2` is not able to contact the `babel-cli` for some reason.

Comment: I am checking on the `babel` `presets`.. please let me know if there is a problem with `babel` settings in my `package.json`

Comment: thanks @stever , after your comment I went ahead and added `jsx` entry in webpack.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest babel(^7.0.0) you should install 'babel-node' this way:

`sudo npm i -g @babel/node`

Do not install via this way, because it will work only for babel 6:

`npm install -g babel-cli`

Documentation looks outdated and suitable for babel 6 version.